# Return value to top level function from callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Trying to export a value that is created by a function and only accessible through a callback. Not sure how to approach this.

```
require("lib").doThing("thing", function(value) {
    // need to get value to the top level in order to export it
});

module.exports = value;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap that in a function with a callback, export the entire function:

```
function getValue(callback) {
    require("lib").doThing("thing", function(value) {
        // need to get value to the top level in order to export it
        callback(value);
    });
}

module.exports.getValue = getValue;
```

Then call:

```
exportedVar.getValue(function(val) {
    console.log(val);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If `doThing` is synchronous, this will work:

```
require("lib").doThing("thing", function(value) {
    module.exports = value;
});
```

If it's asynchronous, you'll have to export an object, and then mutate a property on the object when your callback fires:

```
require("lib").doThing("thing", function(value) {
    module.exports.value = value;
});

module.exports = {};
```

Comment: This may have a timing issue as the loading of your module will have no idea when the exported value is actually there.

Comment: Yup for sure, but those are the only two possible options, other than exporting the async function itself.

Comment: Not quite accurate that those are the only ways.  You can export a promise or the caller can provide a callback that gets called when the value is available.  That's how you deal with async results in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to get it to the top level.  Just export it when you have the value inside the callback or export a promise instead:

```
require("lib").doThing("thing", function(value) {
    // need to get value to the top level in order to export it
    module.exports = value;
});
```

If the above callback above is asynchronous, you will then have a timing issue because someone loading your module won't be able to accurately get the property until after the async function is done and they won't know when that exact timing is.

There are many ways to solve that, but a nifty way is to export a promise instead of the value.  The caller can then call `.then()` on the promise to get the value.

```
module.exports = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    require("lib").doThing("thing", function(value) {
        // need to get value to the top level in order to export it
        resolve(value);
    });
});
```

Then, the caller of this module would do something like this:

```
require('someModule').then(function(value) {
    // process the value here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear what you are trying to do, but you can always return a value out of an anonymous function.

```
module.exports = require("lib").doThing("thing", function(value) {
    // need to get value to the top level in order to export it
    return value;
});
```

Comment: There is no evidence here that returning from the anonymous function will do anything useful to solve the OP's issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 OP's issue is vague and does not describe the behavior he looking for clearly. So this could be a solution or the answers above could be one.